# Extract interface implementation type parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extract an interface's type parameter to use it as parameter for a generic function.

In practice, I have these generic types

```ts
interface ITranslatable<T, K extends keyof T> {
  translations: ITranslation<T, K>
}

export type ITranslation<T, K extends keyof T> =
  {
    lang: string
  } & {
    [P in K]?: T[P];
  };
```

I want to use these types like this

```ts
interface MyType extends ITranslatable<MyType, "name" | "description"> {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

the function I use to is this one :

```ts
export type TranslationKeys<T> = T extends ITranslatable<T, infer K>
  ? K
  : never;

export function translate<T extends ITranslatable<T, TranslationKeys<T>>>(item: T, key: TranslationKeys<T>, language: string = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE) {
  return language === DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
    ? item[key]
    : item.translations?.find(translation => translation.lang === language)?.[key] ?? item[key];
}
```

and I use it like this `translate(myItem, 'name', 'en');` for example.

All of this seems to compile correctly, but every time I use my `translate` function,
the autocompletion for the second argument gives me the complete list of `T`'s keys.
I would like to type my function correctly so that the autocompletion gives me just the
keys I passed as a second parameter when I extend it.

For example, for :

```ts
interface Foo extends ITranslatable<Foo, 'name' | 'description'> {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

it gives me `'id' | 'name' | 'description' | 'translations'` and I'd like it to give me
`'name' | 'description'` instead.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I didn't change my interfaces but changed my function to :

```ts
type Unwrapped<T> = T extends (infer U)[]
  ? U
  : T;

export function translate<T extends ITranslatable<T, K>, K extends keyof T>(
  item: T,
  key: Exclude<keyof Unwrapped<T['translations']>, 'lang'>,
  language: string = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
): string {
  return (
    language === DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
      ? item[key as keyof T]
      : (item.translations
        ?.find(translation => translation.lang === language)
        ?.[key as keyof ITranslation<T, K>]
        ?? item[key as keyof T])
  ) as string;
}
```